# How to resize and image on upload, with Node, Express, Mongoose and Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer, sharp

I tried to resize my image when it's being uploaded but I am not getting my way around it. I am using Node, Expressjs, Mongoose, Multer and Sharp. How do I resize it on upload with Sharp?

Here is my create routes:

```
router.post('/create', upload.single('cover'), async (req, res, next) => {
   const fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null
   let witdth = 100;
   let height = 100;

   sharp(req.file)
   .resize(witdth, height).toFile(req.file.path)


   const event = new Event({
   startingDate: req.body.startingDate,
   closingDate: req.body.closingDate,
   title: req.body.title,
   description: req.body.description,
   eventImage: fileName 
  })
  try {    
    const events = await event.save()
    res.redirect("/events")

   } catch {
    if (event.eventImage != null) {
      removeeventImage(event.eventImage)
   }
    res.render("events/new")
 }
});
```

I required Sharp here:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
```

and here is my upload path:

```
const uploadPath = path.join('public', Event.eventImageBasePath)
const imageMineTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']

const upload = multer({ 
  dest: uploadPath,
  fileFilter:  (req, file, callback) => {
  callback(null, imageMineTypes.includes(file.mimetype) )
 }
})
```

and my model is exporting this path to the route:

```
const eventImageBasePath = 'uploads/eventImages'

module.exports.eventImageBasePath = eventImageBasePath
```

It's giving me this error:

```
(node:7447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Input file is 
 missing
```

How can I resize the image when it's getting uploaded to the database or after being uploaded?

Comment: Based on the basic [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp), it seems you missed the `.toFile()` callback.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i have updated the code with the toFile and the error message that its throwing

Comment: mmm... A couple lines above, you test for the presence of a file... But do not use the result of that test. Try changing `sharp(req.file)` for `sharp(fileName)`. That is a total guess... ;)

Comment: It's still saying the same thing. it still didn't work